# Какой элемент разметки использовать лучше?

Tags: java, android, xml

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой элемент XML удобнее использовать, чтобы при добавлении в него новых View, их размеры автоматически уменьшались, чтобы втиснуться в родительский View?**

Сначала думал использовать *GridView*, но потом понял, что размеры вложенных в него View нединамичны (разве что руками править).

Нужно вот так чтобы получилось (**слева** - до добавления новых View, **справа** - после *(размер контейнера остался тем же, а элементы уменьшились)*):
[image: до добавления вью]
[image: после]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте GridLayout для версий API 21+ (или support.v7.widget.GridLayout для более ранних версий) и используйте вес. Например, вот так:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:rowCount="4">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        ...

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш способ помог!

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `LinearLayout` с вложенными `LinearLayout`. Все вложенные элементы должны иметь вес равный `1`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="verticlal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Теперь, добавляя строки - добавляйте ещё один

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

Каждая ячейка же, чтобы быть равной по ширине своим соседям слева/справа также должна иметь вес равный `1`

Comment: LinearLayout со вложенным весом (если нужно сделать несколько таких строк) не рекомендуется, так как снижает производительность. Хотя для небольших объемов подходит хорошо )

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich, ну, IDE, вроде, обычно предлагает в таких случаях какой-то там атрибут добавить... Что-то типа `baselineAligned` что ли... А так да - лучше через GridLayout какой-нить попробовать запилить.

Comment: Таким способом будет неудобно добавлять новые элементы из джавы.

Comment: @DenisPerfomer, ну почему же? `mainLinear.getChildAt(lineNumber).addView(newImage);`))) А так да - можно и поизящнее задачу решить.